# How to avoid getting plain JSON result in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I have a view that has a button for applying for a job, and this button is redirected to a HttpPost action method that handles the apply logic and then returns a JSON result to the same view. as shown below:

```
// POST: Application/Apply
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(string idUser, int idAnnouncement)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        // Search for the candidate that has the same Hash code as idUser param
        Candidate appliedCandidate = db.Candidates.Where(c => c.CandidateSecondID.Equals(idUser)).FirstOrDefault();

        // todo: check if Candidate is already applyed to job
        var check = db.Applications.Where(a => a.CandidateID.Equals(appliedCandidate.CandidateID) && a.AnnouncementID.Equals(idAnnouncement)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (check == null)
        {
            Application newApp = new Application
            {
                AnnouncementID = idAnnouncement,
                CandidateID = appliedCandidate.CandidateID,
                ApplicationDate = DateTime.Now,
            };
            db.Applications.Add(newApp);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return this.Json(new
            {
                EnableSuccess = true,
                SuccessTitle = "Success",
                SuccessMsg = "Your application has been sent successfully!"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Json(new
            {
                EnableSuccess = false,
                ErrorTitle = "Warning",
                ErrorMsg = "You are already applayed for this Job!"
            });
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: action,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.EnableSuccess) {
            swal(
                result.SuccessTitle,
                result.SuccessMsg,
                'success'
            )
        } else {
            swal(
                result.ErrorTitle,
                result.ErrorMsg,
                'warning'
            )
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

and here is the full view :

```
    @model IEnumerable<JobPostingProject.Models.Announcement>

@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of jobs";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Announcement", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-lg-3 ">
            <div class="title">
                <i class="fas fa-search mr-2"></i>
                <input type="text" name="titleInput" class="title__input form-control border-0" placeholder="Job Title" value="@ViewBag.Job" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="city">
                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-2"></i>
                <input type="text" name="cityInput" class="city__input form-control border-0" placeholder="Location" value="@ViewBag.City" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="categorie">
                @Html.DropDownList("Categories", null, "Job Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="date mb-4">
                @*<i class="fas fa-search mr-2"></i>*@
                <input type="date" name="dateInf" class="title__input form-control" style="border: 1px solid #ced4da; padding-left: 10px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="date mb-4">
                @*<i class="fas fa-search mr-2"></i>*@
                <input type="date" name="dateSup" class="title__input form-control" style=" border: 1px solid #ced4da;
        padding-left: 10px;
" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="level">
                @Html.DropDownList("Levels", ViewBag.Levels as SelectList, "Level", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="text-white text-decoration-none btn btn-primary search__button" />
        @*@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Announcement", null, new { @class = "text-white text-decoration-none btn btn-primary search__button" })*@
    </div>
}




<!--list of all jobs searched for-->

<div class="container mt-5">
    @{
        if (!Model.Any())
        {
            <p class="text-center p-3 text-secondary">No job found with the chosen critiria</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p class="text-secondary">@ViewBag.TotalResults job results found</p>
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="jobs">
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "Application", new { idUser = User.Identity.GetUserId(), idAnnouncement = item.AnnouncementID }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "w-100 AnnonceForm" }))
                            {
                                <div class="job">
                                    <div class="job__header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between flex-wrap mb-0">
                                        <h5 class="job__title">@item.Title</h5>
                                        <h2 class="job__city">@item.Location</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <h5 class="job__datetime">Posted in @item.PublicationDate.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")</h5>
                                    <h5 class="job__company-name mb-4">By @item.Company.Name</h5>
                                    <div class="job__actions d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <p class="job__apply my-0 mr-2">
                                            @Html.ActionLink("More details", "AnnouncementDetails", "Application", new { idAnnouncement = item.AnnouncementID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                                        </p>
                                        @if (!User.IsInRole("Company"))
                                        {
                                            <input type="submit" value="Apply Now" class="btn btn-outline-primary submit-btn">
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    }
</div>

@section AnnouncementIndex {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Home.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Announcement/AnnouncementIndex.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let submitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".submit-btn");
        for (let i = 0; i < submitForms.length; i++) {
            submitButtons[i].addEventListener("submit", e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                var el = this.parentElement;
                while (el.className != 'AnnonceForm') {
                    el = el.parentElement;
                }
                //el is now your parent
                let action = el.attr("action");
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: action,
                    data: {},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("entered success block");
                        if (result.EnableSuccess) {
                            swal(
                                result.SuccessTitle,
                                result.SuccessMsg,
                                'success'
                            )
                        } else {
                            swal(
                                result.ErrorTitle,
                                result.ErrorMsg,
                                'warning'
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
                return false;
            })
        }

    </script>
}
```

BUT, for some reason, I get this plain JSON result instead of actually returning to the success function in the AJAX call.

[image]

Comment: The problem is in the code you aren't showing us: the button is also submitting the form the regular way, cutting off your AJAX code because it makes the browser navigate to the result. You need to cancel the submission event, either by calling `.preventDefault()` on the event or by returning false from the handler function.

Comment: Hi Chris,
Thanks for your comment.
i already used the preventDefault() but it didn't work as expected, and now I tried returning false from the handler function and again, same result.

Comment: I just updated the post, so now u can see the full view

Comment: I can't really do anything with the source code; I would need the final HTML from your browser's source view (Ctrl+U). However you should do some basic debugging first. If there's a syntax error in your JS code it'll kill the script and thus not prevent the default event handling. Add `console.log(...)` commands and check the browser console to find out what's happening and to check variables.

Comment: Inside the for loop, I added a ``` console.log(...) ``` for testing, and it seems that the console actually prints it, but once I click on the Apply button, it redirects me to the view associated with the Apply action method

Comment: You need to put something like `console.log(e)` not just inside the for loop but inside the event handler. Submitting the form should run the function you pass: `e => { .. }` which should stop the submission and run the ajax instead. You need to find out at which point this fails. Also, again, put FINAL RENDERED HTML into the question, ideally as stack snippet (`<>` button) so we can reproduce the issue. This is probably just a really basic error or typo.

Comment: Hey, I just fixed this problem. It was all because of the javascript lol.
I tried debugging line by line and the problem was that I wan't targeting the right HTML element. Thanks for your help! appreciate it!